# Как сделать select phone country code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Пытаюсь реализовать select phone country code, нашел готовое решение на CodePen:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-5 mb-5">
            <div class="form-area">
                <div class="form-inner">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" value="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" value="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="mobile_code" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" name="name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="name">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

$("#mobile_code").intlTelInput({
initialCountry: "in",
separateDialCode: true,
});

но это не совсем то, что нужно. Необходимо, чтобы сверху был список стран(код) , где при нажатии на страну, можно было вводить номер телефона в форме.

Как здесь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам сам код в инпуте нужно отображать или как? Потому что не то чтобы понятно что конкретно Вас сейчас не устраивает. [Show selected dial code option](https://intl-tel-input.com/examples/show-selected-dial-code.html)

Comment: Да, практически то что надо, но надо так-же в инпуте отображать код страны. И не в одну линию формы , а в две: первый список стран, вторая форма(input) phone number

Comment: В этом случае надо иметь список стран с кодами и сам самописный  select